# How to select specific columns from nested relationships in a query with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Model A, has BelongsTo with Model B. Model B has BelogsTo wit Model C

So, I need to make a query and i need to get * from Model A, 2 columns from Model B and other 2 columns from Model C

```
ModelA::query()
->with([
'relationModelB' => function ($query) {
$query->select('id', 'column');
},
'relationModelB.relationModelC' => function ($query) {
$query->select('id', 'column');
}
])
->where('id', $id)
->first();
```

This return all from A, 2 columns from B, but C returns null.

If, I try this query, it returns well, alls columns from 3 models.

```
ModelA::query()
->with(['relationModelB', 'relationModelB'])
->where('id', $id)
->first();
```

What is missing in the first query, to get specific columns from the relation of the relation?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you have to make sure to select any columns that would be needed for the relationship (ids, foreign keys)

Comment: Like I said, if I don't specify, columns, like a select * from, all comes allright, but are too much columns....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```php
ModelA::query()
    ->with(['relationModelB' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['relationModelC' => function($query){
            $query->select('id', 'column');
        })
        ->select('id', 'column');
    }])
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();
```

OR

```
ModelA::query()
    ->with(['relationModelB' => function ($query) {
        $query->with('relationModelC:id,column')
            ->select('id', 'column');
    }])
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### LARAVEL 8

When you want to select specific columns of relationships, both nested or not, **you must include the ones involved into the relationship**, because Eloquent needs them to resolve the relationship itself (as told by [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) in the comments).

In your situation, you must include the foreign key column of relationModelB that refers to relationModelC (let's say *relationModelC_id*). You can handle this in the following way:

```
modelA::with(
    "relationModelB.relationModelC:id,column",
    "relationModelB:id,column,relationModelC_id"
  )
  ->find($id);
```

This works for **belongsTo** relationships that have only one foreign key column. For example, if the relationship is a **morphTo**, you must include also the **type** column.